# Random top/left positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two of each element that needs to be positioned at random in a container without overlapping. My solutions isn't working as I hoped. The code for the top/left:

```
var toparray = [];
var leftarray = [];
var top; 
var left;
for(var z = 0; z<termArray.length*2;z++){
    toparray=toparray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
    leftarray=leftarray.sort(function(c,d){return c-d;});
    toparray[z]=Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+50);
    leftarray[z]=left = Math.floor((Math.random()*800)+50);
    if(toparray[z]<=toparray[z-1]+50){
        toparray[z]=Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+50);
    }
    if(leftarray[z]<=leftarray[z-1]+50){
        leftarray[z]=Math.floor((Math.random()*800)+50);
    }
}
```

I want the elements to be at least 50px away from each other.
They are called and sent to a new document:

```
for(var i = 0; i<termArray.length;i++){ 
    for(var q = 0; q<=1; q++){
        if(q==0){
            top = toparray[i];
            left = leftarray[i];
        }
        else{
            top = toparray[i+1];
            left = leftarray[i+1];
        }
        docBody+='<span style="outline: 1px solid transparent; padding: 20px;top:'+top+'px;left:'+left+'px; cursor: pointer; max-width: 250px; display: table; position: absolute;" id="term'+i+'">'+termArray[i][q]+'</span>';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is what is resolving:
[image]

Any ideas of what is wrong with my logic?
Edit: my array outputs for toparray and leftarray respectively:

[147, 183, 198, 214, 238, 302, 407, 492, 545, 294]

[172, 233, 458, 576, 632, 639, 653, 755, 817, 582]

Comment: You don't include the width of the element. It should be `50px + the current width` to avoid overlapping and 50px spacing in between.

Comment: Exactly!! In your code you don't include width values. Its a simple collision problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @OptimusCrime, these elements don't exist until the document has been generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div#divContainer { float:left; width:600px; height:600px; border-style:solid; }
            div.child { position:absolute; width:40px; height:40px;  border-style:solid; border-width:1px; }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var m_DivListPos = [];
            function PositionOK(x,y) {
                for (var i in m_DivListPos) {
                    var pos = m_DivListPos[i];
                    if (Math.abs(x-pos.x) < 50 ) return false;
                    if (Math.abs(y-pos.y) < 50 ) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            function AddObject() {
                for (var i=0; i<100; i++) { // if not empty space, exit
                    var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+50);
                    console.log (x);
                    var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+50)
                    if (PositionOK(x,y)) {
                        m_DivListPos.push ( {'x':x, 'y':y});
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.className = 'child';
                        div.style.left = x + 'px';
                        div.style.top = y + 'px';
                        document.getElementById('divContainer').appendChild(div);
                        return ;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='AddObject()'> Add object </button>
        <div id='divContainer'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped but hasn't solved the problem. Please see the updated question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794104/jquery-random-top-left-positioning-pre-dom