# jQuery Random Top/Left positioning pre-DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm trying to get random top/left positioning for a random number of elements (spans) that will be at least 50 pixels away from each-other to ensure a clean scatter. The code I have right now follows:

```
function PositionOK(x, y) {
    axisarray.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    for (var i in axisarray) {
        var pos = axisarray[i];
        if (Math.abs(x - pos.x) < 50) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Math.abs(y - pos.y) < 50) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
for (var xy = 0; xy < termArray.length * 2; xy++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
    if (PositionOK(x, y)) {
        axisarray.push({
            'xaxis': x,
            'yaxis': y
        });
    } else axisarray.push({
        'xaxis': x + 50,
        'yaxis': y + 50
    });
}
```

Sample output:
[image]

As you can see, they are not evenly distributed. Some are floating above another, when they should be spread out at least 50px.
Any advice/solutions?

Comment: dont you need something like this: 'xaxis': x + 50 + 'px'?

Comment: One potential problem I see is that while the coordinates are all 50px apart, that doesn't mean the edges of each block will be 50px from each other edge. Since it's only the ORIGIN of the element that is 50px, not the actual border of the element, you're seeing overlap. I'm not sure how I'd solve that, but I'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Comment: You have to take into account the element's width and height as well.

Comment: @jp310, that is being done when generating the document.

Comment: @ProtonBetaDecay yes, I'm pretty sure the problem is the fact that I cannot get the elements width and height before hand to add to its top/left positions

Comment: If you do not know width and height of elements, you can't make sure that it will not overlap.  maybe you can put it first, get it's size and then locate it?  I'll try to get example later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wasn't able to get it pixel-perfect, but this is the best solution I could come up with. Let me know if there's something to make it even better:

```
axisarray = [];
var x, y;
x = y = 0;
for (var xy = 0; xy < termArray.length * 2; xy++) {
    function genxy(shuffle) {

        if (shuffle) {
            axisarray = axisarray.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.xaxis > b.xaxis ? 1 : -1;
            });
            x = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random() * (axisarray[xy - 1].xaxis + 50) + axisarray[xy - 1].xaxis));
            axisarray = axisarray.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.yaxis > b.yaxis ? 1 : -1;
            });
            y = Math.abs(Math.floor(Math.random() * (axisarray[xy - 1].yaxis + 50) + axisarray[xy - 1].yaxis));
        } else {
            axisarray = axisarray.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.xaxis > b.xaxis ? 1 : -1;
            });
            x = Math.floor(Math.random() * x + 100) + 50;
            axisarray = axisarray.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.yaxis > b.yaxis ? 1 : -1;
            });
            y = Math.floor(Math.random() * y + 100) + 50;
        }
    }
    if (xy > 0) {
        genxy(true);
    } else {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 50;
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 50;
    }
    while (x > 800 || y > 500 || x < 0 || y < 0) {
        genxy(false);
    }
    axisarray.push({
        'xaxis': x,
        'yaxis': y
    });
}
```

Sample output below:
[image]
There's still some minor overflow, but I can't do any better

Answer (score 0):

Sequential based solution (up to 12 terms supported until I mess with the css)

```
axisarray = [];
var x, y;
x = y = 0;
for (var xy = 0; xy < termArray.length * 2; xy++) {
    function genxy() {
        if (xy % 3 == 0) {
            var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 60);
            y = axisarray[xy - 1].yaxis + temp;
            x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 125) + 100);
        } else {
            y = axisarray[xy - 1].yaxis;
            x = axisarray[xy - 1].xaxis + 300;
        }
    }
    if (xy > 0 && xy <= 12) {
        genxy();
    } else if (xy > 12) {
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 125) + 100);
        y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 75);
    } else {
        x = 100;
        y = 50;
    }
    if (xy == termArray.length * 2 - 1) axisarray.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    axisarray.push({
        'xaxis': x,
        'yaxis': y
    });
}
```